# Children count not fetched although query fetches everything else

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a function like so:

```
@app.route('/search/')
def search():
    # Handle search conditions
    query = db.session.query(
        Parent.id,
        Parent.name,
        func.count(Children.id),
    )
    query = query.filter(and_(*conditions))  # This comes from "Handle search conditions"
    query = query.outerjoin((Children, Parent.children))
    return jsonify([row._asdict() for row in query.all()])
```

And when called, it properly returns the parents' data:

```
[
  {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Example Parent',
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Another Parent',
  }
]
```

But it doesn't return the count of its children.

What did I do wrong, how do I make it also fetch the child count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the label for the `count` column

```
query = db.session.query(
    Parent.id,
    Parent.name,
    func.count(Children.id).label('count'),
)
```